# Is it possible to set `var` as const in imagej-macro?

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

Can anyone show me how to secure the value of variable in imagej macro script?

In general, there is a key word, such as `const`, to ensure the variable unchangable in most of programming language, but in imagej macro this optional keyword cannot be identified.

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageJ macro language](https://imagej.net/Macros) does not support constants. Use one of the [other supported scripting languages](https://imagej.net/Scripting) instead.